# Open AI Whisper is returning the transcription in English instead of the native language

Tags: python, speech-recognition, openai-whisper

When I use the open AI whisper model on Hindi audio, it returns the transcription in English instead of Hindi.

How do I get the output in Hindi itself? Is there a setting that can be changed?

```
mel = whisper.log_mel_spectrogram(audio).to(model.device)
options = whisper.DecodingOptions(language = 'hi')
result = whisper.decode(model, mel, options)
print(result.text)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: If you are trying using the `base` model, try `large` or `medium`. The issue with wrong script for Hindi is already reported here: https://github.com/openai/whisper/discussions/118

Answer (score 0):

I recommend loading your model as for example `base.hi`.

Edit: Here's an example:

```
model = whisper.load_model('base.hi')
result = model.transcribe(file_path)
```

Comment: You might want to explain why you recommend that, how it is supposed to help.

Comment: Thanks, added a more elaborate example.

Comment: Thanks. But an example neither explains why you recommend it nor how it is supposed to help.